# Use C# to trigger java script code inside an html page

Tags: c#, javascript

If I have an html page with all the scrips in it, how can feed this html to some sort of egine in .NET and use C# could to simulate user interaction with that page (like problematically presses a buttom or cause the web page to request a next page of a grid inside the html file) which would cause the page to to do whatever server interaction it would have done if it was inside the browser and get the C# engine to recieve the respose from the server?

Does such engine exist that could host html file and be sent events programtically? What does such approach called?

Comment: can you clarify if this is a business function you need to perform or is this in order to do automated testing on your html pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few pieces of software available to do what you want, but I don't know if they're controllable via C#. Why do you need to use C#?

The software I know of for doing this is ....

- Selenium
- Watin

or as Philipp Schmid suggested, you could write your own using a webbrowser control and searhing for controls, setting the text values of them and simulating click events.

Comment: Is there a way to use Watin in slient mode?